# Submenu didn't work and became a text only

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with submenu that I use from bootstrap. It became a text not a button to go another page, here is some code that I use

This is the latest vue and bootstrap 4, I've tried some tutorial's but didn't work

```
<div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
        <div class="menu_section">
          <ul class="nav side-menu">
            <li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Penjualan <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
              <ul class="nav child_menu">
                <li><a>Pemesanan penjualan<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                  <ul class="nav child_menu">
                    <li><router-link to="/pemesananPembelian">P.O Penjualan</router-link></li>
                    <li><router-link to="/konfirmasipemesananPenjualan">P.O Konfirmasi</router-link></li>
                    <li><router-link to="/dikirimpemesananPenjualan">P.O Dikirim</router-link></li>
                    <li><router-link to="/batalpemesananPenjualan">P.O Batal</router-link></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
```

I want to make a sub menu to go another page, but the submenu didn't work and become a text`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the official doc:
https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link

```
<router-link tag="li" to="/foo">
  <a>/foo</a>
</router-link>
```